# Quantile regression with Stata

Tags: stata, quantile-regression

Is there a way to test the equality of quantile regression coefficients in one go using Stata? For example can I do the comparison of the coefficients of the 10th, 25th, 50th, 75th and the 90th quantiles using one single command in Stata?

Answer (score 6):

Consider the example below.

```
sysuse auto, clear
sqreg price weight length foreign, ///
      quantile(.25 .5 .75) reps(100)
test [q25=q50=q75]:weight
```